# The differences between infinitive and present participle phrases as postpositive attributives to express something that happens in the future

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

> The boy who will come to see you tomorrow will bring you that book.

Can this sentence be changed to either of the following?

a. The boy coming to see you tomorrow will bring you that book.

*or*

b. The boy to come to see you tomorrow will bring you that book.

Which one would be the better choice?

Comment: a. is fine and natural. But b. is ungrammatical because "boy" cannot license the infinitival clause here.

Comment: To use the infinitival clause there, it would have to be "The boy who is to come to see you tomorrow, will bring you ..." but that is somewhat clunky.

Comment: @BillJ — *The boy to do the job has not been born yet.*?

Comment: @TinfoilHat The infinitival clause in your example is a modifier (an infinitival relative clause) not a complement.